# Shapefiles and adding label data

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

**Introduction:**

I'm still fairly new to GIS and have only had about 3 weeks experience. I set up an *OSM* server locally with *.osm.pbf* data and it worked just fine. When I pulled the map in the browser, which implemented *leaflet*, all the names of streets, buildings, and other objects were already included in the data.

**The Problem:**

To increase my knowledge I went on to create a *TinyOWS* server with *WFS-T standardization*. To get the data for this server I pulled multiple states in the form of shapefiles from http://download.geofabrik.de/. When I load these shapefiles into *QGIS* I get all the streets, buildings, etc.., but no labels and names for any of the information. I can't find much helpful information on the internet for this, which means I'm thinking of model all wrong, or I'm visiting the wrong resources.

**Question:**

*How do I get labels for streets, building, etc..., for shapefiles?*

Answer (score 1):

Double click your layer in QGIS, find the Label menu, label your layer.

Comment: Although your answer is right, we look for more elongated answers. You could insert the menu hierarchy, or insert an image of the lable icon as well. BTW in layer properties you can also access the label menu.